# Equivalent of Rust's try! macro in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-macros

Rust's `try!` macro unwraps `Result`s.  `Ok` values are unwrapped; `Err` causes the enclosing method to return immediately with `Err`.  Implementation here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.try!.html

This is roughly equivalent to Scala `Option.getOrElse(return None)`.

Is it possible to write the equivalent macro in Scala for `Option`s?  It seems the macro would need to check that the enclosing method's return type is `Option`.  I found some relevant discussion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/BH0xz74f4Zk  If so, how?

This would be really nice.  It could perhaps be generalized to unwrap other types such as `Future` and `Try`.  This is weaker than but similar to what the effectful project accomplishes: https://github.com/pelotom/effectful.  In fact, I suppose you could achieve this using effectful but effectful requires the entire block to be enclosed in the macro, while `try!` uses `return` to allow a more local syntax, which is (arguably) nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need a macro?
If you don't want to work with exceptions but instead return an Option you could also try a for comprehension. That approach also works for futures and trys btw.

```
def f1(): Option[Int] = ???
def f2(): Option[String] = ???
def f3(): Option[Double] = ???

def test(): Option[String] = {
  for {
    i <- f1()
    s <- f2()
    d <- f3()
  } yield {
    val n = i * 2
    s + (d * n)
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I want a macro.  Rust's `try!` lets us unwrap values with very little syntactic overhead - no indentation.  I want to emulate the same thing in Scala.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this (in the REPL) with:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros

def impl[T](c: reflect.macros.whitebox.Context)(opt: c.Expr[Option[T]]): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  q"$opt.getOrElse(return None)"
}

def unwrap[T](opt: Option[T]): T = macro impl[T]
```

Then I can use it as follows:

```
def concat(str1: Option[String], str2: Option[String]): Option[String] = {
  Some(unwrap(str1) + unwrap(str2))
}

concat(Some("hello"), Some(" world")) == Some("hello world")
concat(Some("hello"), None) == None
```

(Note that in a sbt project, macros need to be defined in a separate project from their usage.)